# Is using the - symbol with the Associative Law of multiplication invalid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, axioms

I was trying to prove that $-(x + y) = -x - y$ and as you can see in the image below, I took the liberty of using the $-$ symbol as a number and applying the associative law with it. Is it kosher in all rigorousness given the axioms professional mathematicians use?
[image]

Comment: If you're not assuming commutativity I feel like it should be $-(x+y) = -y -x$.

Comment: @Cocopuffs Commutativity is assumed in the reals.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Oh, I didn't see that.  Then why not use it? Just $(x+y) + -x - y = (y + x) + -x - y = 0$ by associativity.

Comment: There's a problem in there. You're "pulling out" the $-$ under the "associative law". I guess you know that, given $x$, $(-1) \cdot x =-x$ is its additive inverse. So what you want to do is to use the distributive law as $-(x+y)=(-1)\cdot(x+y)=(-1)\cdot x+(-1)\cdot y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x+y)+(-x-y)=(y+x)+(-x-y)=y+(x-x)+(-y)=y+0+(-y)=0$$
So $(x+y)$ is the additive inverse of $(-x-y)$. Hence $-(x+y)=-x-y$

Answer (score 2):

Well the LHS of your equation is just saying "the additive inverse of $x+y$".

So all you have to show is that the additive inverse of $x+y$ really is the RHS of the equation, i.e. $-x-y$, then by uniqueness of inverses in a group the two must be equal.